# What type of tags can I use on my highly secured website to track data (cookie) ?

Tags: javascript, security, iframe, tags

working on webmarketing, my IT is telling me that Iframe tags are more and more touchy regarding security matters. I am not allowed to use javascript tags either however image tags are too simple to let me piggyback third party tags.(because they do not allow scripts to be executed)
Any ideas of what type of tags or type of code I could use or modify to fulfill both technical and commercial conditions, please?
(a mix of javascript and flash website)
thank you

Comment: Use objects? http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/195687-iframe-replacement/  Also, to provide a bit of background, iFrames HAD security issues in older versions of IE, significant ones, but that was last decade.

Answer (score 0):

you could use some server side scripting language (eg PHP) as your image file source. That way, you execute whatever you need server side, while serving the "simple image". And example :

```
 <img src="/images/image.php?img=asdf" />
```

on the server side, you can have a PHP session, along with any data that's relevant to the request. Depending on what type of data you want to harvest, it might be difficult/impossible without any Javascript.